# How do I limit Altair tooltip to only two numbers after the decimal point?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, altair

[Altair graph in Jupyter Lab showing tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnqBp.png)

Comment: See here for an [example](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2058). I don't have your code, so I'm guessing, but I think the following code support is possible. `alt.Tooltip(..., format='.2f')`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `format` argument to `alt.Tooltip` to customize the tooltip format. It accepts a [d3-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format) string, which allows a wide range of possible specifications (including decimal points, percentages, dates/times, currencies, etc.). If you use `format='.2f'` it will format the tooltip as a floating point number with two digits beyond the decimal. For example:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'value': [2.548493, 3.6284932, 4.7148392]
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    y='name',
    x='value',
    tooltip=alt.Tooltip('value', format='.2f')
)
```